# site not opening after closing system backcup in admin panel

Tags: backup

i started to take backup of site using admin panel > system > backup

after Internet got disconnected. Now i am unable to open the frontend and backend of site.

Error:

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

please help me to find solution.

Comment: Clear /var/locks and restart mysql what happens?

Comment: restart your mysql and try it will work

Comment: @sr_magento is it safe to delete " var/locks?

Comment: @hariharan 
 
will it be any other problem if i restart mysql?

Comment: no. if u restart it will not affect anything.. just try

Comment: yes its safe to clear the locks, clear them restart mysql. As Marius pointed out if there is a maintenance flag you will need to clear that as well.

Comment: yes @sr_magento , as Marius told i checked it,, but there was no maintanance.flag, restarted , working fine now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its deadlocked. Restart your mysql and clear cache.

Comment: will it be any other problem if i restart mysql?

Comment: no prbm.. restart

Comment: did it fixed????

Answer (score 2):

When a backup is starting the website is put on maintenance. Remove the file `maintanance.flag` and it should work again.

Comment: unfortunately , there is no maintanace.flag is added at root of the site?

Comment: @BabyinMagento2. No problem. sorry I wasn't spot on, on this one. I took a shot. This is what usually happened to me.

Comment: you don't need to be sorry, i know you faced all kinds of problems happened  in magento.